# Querying in MS Access 2013 excluding special characters

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to create an update query in MS Access where I will pull a few fields of information from one table if one of the fields matches and the rest are blank.  For example:

```
**Table 1**         
SKU        Description  Weight  Lead Time
C210657    NULL         NULL    NULL
221AB0909  NULL         NULL    NULL
VA12345    NULL         NULL    NULL
221AB09    NULL         NULL    NULL    

**Table 2**         
SKU             Description Weight   Lead Time
F-210-223.2     Hammer      2.1      3.1
201-ABF-345     Car         12546.0  65.0
C_210657        Apple       0.2      1.0
34_AA_332       Puppy       5.5      55.0
221 AB 0909     Stereo      12.0     875.0
VA12345_123-A   Labor       0.0      0.0
```

So I want the query to fill in columns 2 through 4 of table 1 with information from table 2.  All four of the items in table 1 have a match in table 2, there are just special characters (-, _, ., ), that are in the way.  How can I have the query ignore them?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which way you go depends on what you're willing to do. If it's a big database, you might want to add a new field [SKU_Index] that is SKU with the special characters removed and link on that.

If that's not a possibility, then you can do a calculated subquery and link on the calculated field...but it can be a little slow.

You would need to write a procedure that removes the special characters from a passed string. Let me know if you would like help with that.

Then you do a query on Table 2 like this:

`Select SKU2:RemoveSpecialChars([SKU]), Description, Weight, [Lead Time] From [Table 2];`

RemoveSpecialChars() would be your procedure.

You save that query (let's call it PreQuery). Create a new query and bring in PreQuery and Table 1 linking SKU from Table 1 to SKU2 from PreQuery, and update the relevant fields.

Ideally, cause storage is cheap, I would keep a second field without the special characters and perhaps index on it.

Here's example code for how that would work:

```
Public Function RemoveSpclChars(strIn As String) As String
  ' Comments  : removes any special characters
  ' Parameters: strIn - string to check
  ' Returns   : resulting string with removed special characters, can be empty
  '
  Dim lngCounter, intChar As Integer
  Dim chrTmp As String * 1
  Dim strTmp As String

  On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
  strTmp = ""

  ' Walk through the string
  For lngCounter = 1 To Len(strIn)
    ' Get the current character
    chrTmp = Mid$(strIn, lngCounter)
    intChar = Asc(chrTmp)
    ' Test if alpha or numeric only
    If (intChar >= Asc("a") And intChar <= Asc("z")) Or (intChar >= Asc("0") And intChar <= Asc("9")) Then
      strTmp = strTmp & chrTmp
    End If
  Next lngCounter

PROC_EXIT:
  RemoveSpclChars = strTmp
  Exit Function

PROC_ERR:
  Dim strErr As String
  strTmp = "ERROR: " & Trim(Str(Err.Number)) & ":" & Err.Description
  Resume PROC_EXIT

End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that I simplified the request, but I will actually be doing four queries in succession each against a different table each containing a different type of SKUs.  Also, all four of the tables are being continually updated, additions and removals, and two of the tables are updated by my ERP, so while I could add a field to them, it would be very difficult.  Also, Table 1 could theoretically contain special characters that I would want to ignore.

Comment: So, and correct me if I'm wrong, you need to update Table 1 whenever there are blanks in the Description, Weight, and Lead Time (in your example)...right? Does that data change so you'd have to update existing entries (where there is data in Description, Weight, and Lead Time)? I imagine Lead Time might change from time to time. I'm just trying to determine your "base" set of data that you'll be updating to limit it for the joining on a calculated field (sub query) method. I have one other idea if that doesn't appear to be viable.

Comment: Good questions, let me give a fuller explanation of the intent.  **FYI:**  This is going to take several posts due to the character limit.

Comment: **Background**  I have four teams that each maintain a list of products. Each teams assigns an item # that is only relevant to them, but they also store the manufacturer's part # in order to be able to expedite purchasing.  They regularly add and remove items from their lists.

Comment: **My Project**  I have customers that request pricing for products and they supply manufacturer part # when they request that pricing.  I want to be able to use the information they supply me to lookup and see which, if any, of the four teams has that product available already.  The challenge is that many times the customers omit the special characters or in some cases they even put them in the wrong spot.

Comment: Ahhh. the joys of dealing with users and customers! So, do you see the subquery idea with the "RemoveSpclChars()" working for you (since adding a field would not be viable)?

Comment: Yes please, that would be great.

Comment: I added code to my original answer. Let me know if you need anything else.